# SQLite cumulative sum sorting

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'm looking to do the difference between 2 cumulative sums and sorted by date, but the date column is on a different table to the date which seems to be causing problems. (`date` is on the `eventinfo` table and the columns I want to use are on the `results` table).

I want to get a running total on the difference between `results.prize` and `results.totalbuyin` with the total ordered by `eventinfo.date` where `results.event=eventinfo.eventname`.  I would also like to filter query by `results.playername` so I can get a running total for any individual player.  I can get the date column to appear in the query and order by date but sum is happening in order of ID number:

Results Table

```
ID;PlayerName;TotalBuyIn;Prize;Rebuys;Event;
1;Ole Schemion;100000;1062785;0;Aria $100K July 2014;
2;Isaac Haxton;100000;813394;0;Aria $100K July 2014;
3;Daniel Colman;100000;796821;0;Aria $100K July 2014;
4;Daniel Cates;100000;297000;0;Aria $100K July 2014;
5;Cary Katz;100000;0;0;Aria $100K July 2014;
```

EventInfo Table

```
ID;EventName;Date;Location;Country;PokerTour;UniquePlayers;Rebuys;
1;ACOP 500k 2014;2014-11-01;City of Dreams;Macau;APPT;52;50;
2;ACOP Super High Roller 2015;2015-11-13;City of Dreams;Macau;APPT;34;17;
3;Alpha 8 Florida 2013;2013-08-26;Seminole Hard Rock;USA;WPT;18;3;
4;Alpha 8 Florida 2015;2015-01-17;Seminole Hard Rock;USA;WPT;6;0;
5;Aria $100K July 2014;2014-02-14;Emperor Palace;South Africa;WPT;9;1;
```

In these tables `results.event=eventinfo.eventname`

Failed Query

```
SELECT t1.id,
   t1.prize,
   t1.TotalBuyIn,
   t1.PlayerName,
   (SUM(t2.prize)) - (SUM(t2.totalbuyin)),
   eventinfo.Date
FROM results t1
INNER JOIN results t2 ON t1.id >= t2.id and t2.PlayerName = "Erik Seidel"
INNER JOIN eventinfo ON t1.Event = eventinfo.EventName
Where t1.PlayerName = "Erik Seidel"
GROUP BY t1.id
ORDER BY eventinfo.Date
```

Current Output

```
t1.id;t1.prize;t1.TotalBuyIn;t1.PlayerName;(SUM(t2.prize)) - (SUM(t2.totalbuyin));eventinfo.Date;
1314;618139;98902;Erik Seidel;135685;2011-01-22;
1292;2472555;247255;Erik Seidel;-383552;2011-01-27;
1401;1092780;100000;Erik Seidel;1128465;2011-05-18;
1425;0;100000;Erik Seidel;1028465;2011-12-09;
1127;0;100000;Erik Seidel;-2341985;2012-01-05;
```

Line 8 is obviously the problem but I can't seem to rewrite the code to fix it. Putting in `t1.date>=t2.date` won't work even though I thought I had joined the tables.  I'm using SQLite3 if that makes a difference.

Comment: I would suggest that you modify your question to include sample data and desired results.  A non-working query is amazing often not sufficient for communicating what one wants to do to other people not familiar with the problem.

Comment: If eventinfo.EventName is a Char field, it would probably be a good idea to add a Unique ID column to the eventinfo table.  Using text columns for keys is generally not a recommended practice.

Comment: What is the results.id column for?  At first glance it appears to be a UID, but you are using it as if it is a value that pertains to the Player.  Does the results table have multiple rows per player?

Comment: Sorry, I'm extremely new to this. I've made edits and tried to make it more clear, let me know if I need to add anything else

Comment: yes there can be multiple rows for each player, each row is a entry for a event and a player can have played multiple events

Comment: eventinfo table has a unique ID column, as shown in the edit

Comment: What is the desired result for the example data?

Comment: This is a database of poker tournament results. I wanted to create a query that will allow me to make a profit/loss graph for individual players

Comment: I want a list of results from a particular player, listing profit (prize-totalbuyin) and work out the cumulative sum worked out by adding the results in date order, although the event date is on a different table (eventinfo).

Comment: To clarify your question, edit it. And please show the results that you want to get from the example data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would create the first query like this:

```
SELECT Date, EventName, (SUM(Prize)) - (SUM(TotalBuyIn)) AS Net
FROM results
INNER JOIN eventinfo ON Event = EventName
GROUP BY Date, EventName
ORDER BY eventinfo.Date
```

I would create the second query like this:

```
SELECT PlayerName, (SUM(Prize) - SUM(TotalBuyIn)) AS Net, Date, EventName
FROM Results
INNER JOIN EventInfo ON Event = EventName
GROUP BY PlayerName
ORDER BY Date
```

Here is a tip:
You created an integer Primary Key (ID) in the EventInfo table and it is good practice to use these integer values in the Event column in the Results table.  Using text values to join tables together can create unnecessary headaches.

UPDATE:
The following solution only works for one player, but you had specified a specific player in your example so I believe this is what you are seeking.

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE TEMP AS SELECT Date, PlayerName, Prize, TotalBuyIn, SUM(t1.Prize - T1.TotalBuyIn) AS Net
FROM Results t1
INNER JOIN EventInfo t3 ON t1.Event = t3.EventName
GROUP BY t1.PlayerName, t3.Date;

SELECT Date, PlayerName, Prize, TotalBuyIn, 
(SELECT SUM(Net) FROM TEMP t2 WHERE t1.Date >= t2.Date AND PlayerName='Erik Seidel') AS Net
FROM TEMP t1
WHERE PlayerName='Erik Seidel'
GROUP BY Date
ORDER BY Date;

DROP TABLE TEMP;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer,

Comment: Thanks for your answer, neither seems to be what I'm looking for though, probably because I didn't explain it properly.  I would like a running total for ('results.prize' - 'results.totalbuyin') for each 'results.event' a particular player is in, in date order for that player.  If you see in my question, the output in my qurey is close to what I want but the running total is in order of 'results.id' instead of 'eventinfo.date' which is what I want.  Thanks for the tip about using the primary key in other tables, makes perfect sense now I look at it.

Comment: still can't really explain it properly, the running total in my example query, although sorted by date, the running total is calculated as if it is ordered in 'results.id' order

Comment: @AdamChurcher  I updated my answer.  Please see if it is closer to what you are needing.

Comment: Thanks for the update, I am currently getting this error: SQL Error: table TEMP already exists with your query

Comment: @AdamChurcher Just run _DROP TABLE TEMP;_  and then run everything again

Comment: @AdamChurcher  Did my Update work for you?  If so, please accept my solution.  If not, let me know what results you are getting.  Thanks!

Comment: @Steve Sort of, I can get the command to work if running it as 3 separate statements, for some reason it won't all work as one, but at least I am getting the results I wanted.  When execute the first time it runs but doesn't some up with results, second time it runs and says table temp already exists